# onWindowFocusChanged() doesn't call with false, only with true

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a problem in my game with playing sound while device's display is on the lock screen, like discussed [there](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/making-android-games-that-play-nice.html). For some reasons i can't require user input to resume game, so I want to catch onWindowFocusChanged events for resuming game. Unfortunately described solution doesn't work in my case.

Application use landscape orientation. AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.application.applicationname"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">

    <!-- main application activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.application.applicationname.Activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
              android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

When I use phone with portrait orientation, something wrong. On start all is good. simple log:

```
02-12 18:18:28.329: E/activity(15215): onDestroy called
02-12 18:18:28.329: E/activity(15215): onCreate called
02-12 18:18:28.389: E/activity(15215): onStart called
02-12 18:18:28.389: D/activity(15215): onResumeCalled
02-12 18:19:06.329: D/activity(15215): onWindowFocusChanged called with focus = true
```

But when I press power button to lock device and then unlock it:

```
02-12 18:30:55.629: E/activity(22605): onPause called
02-12 18:30:55.629: E/activity(22605): onStop called
02-12 18:30:58.379: E/activity(22605): onDestroy called
02-12 18:30:58.839: E/activity(22605): onCreate called
02-12 18:30:58.839: E/activity(22605): onStart called
02-12 18:30:58.839: D/activity(22605): onResumeCalled
02-12 18:30:58.849: D/activity(22605): onPauseCalled
02-12 18:30:59.219: D/activity(22605): onResumeCalled
02-12 18:30:59.479: D/activity(22605): onPauseCalled
02-12 18:30:59.559: E/activity(22605): onStop called
02-12 18:34:01.899: E/activity(22605): onRestart called
02-12 18:34:01.899: E/activity(22605): onStart called
02-12 18:34:01.909: D/activity(22605): onResumeCalled
02-12 18:34:20.409: D/activity(22605): onPauseCalled
02-12 18:34:20.409: E/activity(22605): onStop called
02-12 18:34:20.409: E/activity(22605): onDestroy called
02-12 18:34:20.609: E/activity(22605): onCreate called
02-12 18:34:20.609: E/activity(22605): onStart called
02-12 18:34:20.609: D/activity(22605): onResumeCalled
02-12 18:34:20.769: D/activity(22605): onWindowFocusChanged called with focus = true
```

onWindowFocusChanged(false) never calls, and solution described in link before doesn't work.

Also I'm a bit worried about a lot of calls onDestroy/onCreate while device is locking/unlocking. As I understood, it happens because activity changes it's orientation from landscape (for game) to portrait (for device lock screen) and returns to landscape. But with such destroying activity there is no time to call onWindowFocusChanged(false).

So, my questions:

1. How to solve original problem with sound playing on lock screen?
2. Is it possible not to call onDestroy/onCreate many times?

Thanks for your attention.

**UPD** I have implemented solution from [here](http://www.giderosmobile.com/forum/discussion/comment/12047#Comment_12047), and on my devices all works well, but I'm not sure that this solution is completely right. In first link:

> If the device falls asleep on its own, or if the user locks the phone and then immediately unlocks it, your app may not receive any focus changed messages at all.

So, I'm not sure that onWindowFocusChanged(true) will be called in all cases. Is that possible solution?

**UPD 2** About multiple calls onDestroy/onCreate : As wrote in google Activity API about Configuration changes, I have tried to intercept configuration changes for display orientation, but it doesn't work well for me.

Answer (score 0):

To the first answer: You can consider the option of handle the event of lonk/unlock screen, instead of handle the focus change: android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON, android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF.

This way you can notice when the phone is locked/unlocked and handle the sound issue.

Regarding 2nd question, that may be related with the orientation config changes. Probably you're not handling the event as Android expects and it tries to make a turn around. But this one I have no idea how to solve.

Comment: I have implemented screen events as described [in this link](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/), but SCREEN_ON event occurs after turning screen on and before unlocking display. Is there any special intents that occurs after unlocking display?